# How to separate the data on mysql in one table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to the make the data like as follows

```
<ul>
    1 | Adam
    2 | Bruno     <----- using LIMIT 3
    3 | Charlie
</ul>
<ul>
    4 | Dowm
    5 | Emely     <----- using LIMIT 3
    6 | Fanta
</ul>
<ul>
    7 | Ghost
    8 | Heli     <----- using LIMIT 3
    9 | India
</ul> ..... etc
```

And this my code

```
$query = "select * from data LIMIT 3";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
    echo "<ul>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
        $id = $row['id']; $name = $row['name'];
        echo $id ."|". $name;
    }
    echo "</ul>";


$query2 = "select * from data LIMIT 3 AFTER id number 3"; <--- here
$result2 = $mysqli->query($query2);
    echo "<ul>";
    while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
        $id2 = $row2['id']; $name2 = $row2['name'];
        echo $id2 ."|". $name2;
    }
    echo "</ul>";
```

So there is really only 3 points, but Followed by subsequent Data. `select * from data LIMIT 3 AFTER id number 3"`.. I do not want to merge, because different places. Is it possible to derive any multiple of 3? Only one select? Only using one `select * from data LIMIT 3`

Comment: Just select everything and split things into 3's in the PHP script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use LIMIT in SQL. Use a counter in PHP and add `"</ul><ul>"` after every three rows:

```
$query = "select * from data";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

$counter = 0;
echo "<ul>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
    if ($counter != 0 && $counter % 3 == 0) {
        echo "</ul><ul>";
    }
    $id = $row['id']; $name = $row['name'];
    echo "<li>" . $id ."|". $name . "</li>";
    ++$counter;
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Yea thats what I ment

Answer (score 0):

You can use limit and offset together. So the limit is 3.
The idea after offset is: Return only 3 records, start on record offset+1.

Create a variable $offset=0 then increment this variable by 3.
So your query will look like
$query="select * from data limit 3 offset ".$offset;

I guess this can help you to continue.